# Solitaire python

Tags: python

I have code here for moving a card from the deck to the foundation pile. I've imported the necessary details, etc. My problem is, it's too long. Is there any way to make it shorter? How? Thanks :)

```
def dtof():
    suit = raw_input("enter suit: ")
    v = trash.pop()
    if suit == "D":
        if card.suitNumber[v.suit] == 1:
            if card.rankNumber[v.rank] == 0:
                Diamond.append(v)
            elif card.rankNumber[v.rank] == card.rankNumber[Diamond[-1].rank] + 1:
                Diamond.append(v)
            else:
                trash.append(v)
            return Diamond[-1]
        else:
            trash.append(v)
    elif suit == "H":
        if card.suitNumber[v.suit] == 2:
            if card.rankNumber[v.rank] == 0:
                Heart.append(v)
            elif card.rankNumber[v.rank] == card.rankNumber[Heart[-1].rank] + 1:
                Heart.append(v)
            else:
                trash.append(v)
            return Heart[-1]
        else:   
            trash.append(v)
    elif suit == "C":
        if card.suitNumber[v.suit] == 4:
            if card.rankNumber[v.rank] == 0:
                Clubs.append(v)
            elif card.rankNumber[v.rank] == card.rankNumber[Clubs[-1].rank] + 1:
                Clubs.append(v)
            else:
                trash.append(v)
            return Clubs[-1]
        else:
            trash.append(v)
    elif suit == "S":
        if card.suitNumber[v.suit] == 3:
            if card.rankNumber[v.rank] == 0:
                Spade.append(v)
            elif card.rankNumber[v.rank] == card.rankNumber[Spade[-1].rank] + 1:
                Spade.append(v)
            else:
                trash.append(v)
            return Spade[-1]
        else:
            trash.append(v)
    else:
        trash.append(v)
```

Comment: Code being long is not necessarily a problem.  Please be more specific about what you're worried about. Also, consider posting these kind of questions in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging Diamond, Heart, Clubs and Spade into a single dictionary, with the key being suit.